Data Permission on each microservice based on Authenticated User
I am wondering if someone has implemented Data Access Permission (row level permission/filtering of data) based on authenticated user in microservice architecture. Just to give you a background, imagine that there is a Company who works on different Projects. There are many Employees who work for that Company. There are different roles of Employees, SysAdmin who can edit/view projects... and SysUsers who only have Read access to the projects. Now till here things are quite Simple. I am using the same approach on the API level to fetch the Role from logged in User JWT and based on that allow or disallow the execution of Action.
Just to give the design idea, I have some of the following services in the system (not all the services are displayed)
Projects
Employees
Billing
UserAccess
Now one of the requirement of this system is, only certain Employees will have access to certain Projects. so imagine that in the system your have 3 users (User1, User2, User3) and 5 projects (Project1, Project2.... Project5)..... In the system User1 is SysAdmin so he should be able to edit/view projects.... But User1 only has access to Project1 and Project5.... So inside the Projects service, when User1 tries to fetch the list of Projects, he should only see Project1 and Project5. Similarly in the Billing service, User1 should only be able to view/edit Billing data related to Project1 and Project5. Also, in the above example, I have only talked about permission on Projects, but there are other Entities in the system (in different services) which needs similar data level permissions...
I have been thinking about different solutions to address this problem.....
Solution # 1) Put all the Project ids that a User has access to in the Authentication token.. and in each service, get those project ids from ExecutionContextAccessor and filter the data accordingly.... but then Projects isn't the only thing that has user permission, there are other Entities that has similar data level permission, and putting all those entities in the token doesn't feel like a good solution to me...
Solution # 2) Put all the permissions in the UserAccess service..... and each service makes a query to UserAccess service to fetch the permissions before executing any Command or Query and filter the data accordingly.... that creating a coupling between UserAccess and other services...
Solution # 3) Each service should have it's own permissions defined.... for example, on the Projects service, there is something called ProjectPermissions which consists of UserId and ProjectId...... similarly in the Billing service there is going to be a BillingPermissions entity/table that would be used to filter the data....... in other services, there will be similar {Entity}Permissions that would be used..... This way, all the services in the system needs to know about the UserId of the user... so anytime a new user is created, an integration even will fire and all services will have that UserId.
Solution # 4) Combination of solution#2 and solution#3...... All the permissions will be maintained in *UserAccess service but anytime a new permission will be created/modified and integration even will fire and Other services (Projects, Billing etc) will take those permission and keep a copy of it... that way each service will do the filtering on the service level without communicating to UserAccess service....
Or if there is any other solution that someone has used in the system for handling similar Permissions in modular or microservice architecture and would like to share....
Thanks
